# XSLT transformation to eliminate nestings

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I am trying to use an XSLT to remove unnecessary nestings in my input XML. Here is an outline of my input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Application>
  <Applicants>
     <Applicant>
       <Id> 1 </Id>
     </Applicant>
     <Applicant>
       <Id> 2 </Id>
     </Applicant>
  </Applicants>
</Application>
```

Now, post transformation this is my desired output :

```
<Application>
  <Applicants>
     <Id> 1 </Id>
  </Applicants>
  <Applicants>
     <Id> 2 </Id>
  </Applicants>
</Application>
```

Can someone help me out on this? I am new to XSLT transformations

Comment: What have you tried? Why didn't it work?

Comment: I tried using <xsl:keys>  to match <Applicants> and remove <Applicant> tag.
As I said I am new to this, any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Don't think of it as "removing" something. Think of it as "not copying" something. So, basically you want to transform all matches of "Applicants/Applicant" to just "Applicants".

Comment: Yes correct, for each <Applicant> , the output should have one <Applicants> . The output should not have <Applicant> itself.

Comment: Exactly. You can do that by matching the respecting XPath. Have a look into this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms754602(v=vs.85)

Comment: It can be written down as 3 simple templates: 1. `Applicants`: drop the node and apply templates to children. 2. `Applicant`: rename to `Applicants` and apply templates to children 3. everything else: copy as is (identity template)

Comment: dropping Applicants in 1) will remove its child as well. I dont think i follow your suggestion, can you show your solution xslt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mention in the comment, the task at hand can be performed in 3 templates:

- `Applicants`: drop the node and apply templates to children.
- `Applicant`: rename to Applicants and apply templates to children
- everything else: copy as is (identity template)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="Applicants">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Applicant">
  <xsl:element name="Applicants">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<!--Identity template, provides default behavior that copies all content into the output -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: okay! i was trying this :
<xsl:template match="Applicants">
  <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
</xsl:template>

Answer (score -1):

Or simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Application">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="Applicants/Applicant">
            <Applicants>
                <xsl:copy-of select="Id"/>
            </Applicants>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```